# stopifnot() fails for one expression in ... and doesnt work as I expect it to. Are my expectations correct?

Tags: r, error-handling

Description of stopifnot from R Documentation

> **Description**
>
> If any of the expressions in ... are not all TRUE, stop is called,
>   producing an error message indicating the first of the elements of ...
>   which were not true.
>
> **Usage**
>
> stopifnot(...)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> ...    any number of (logical) R expressions, which should evaluate to
>   TRUE.

Sometimes the expressions in ... dont evaluate to TRUE. Consider the error message for the the below scenario

```
a <- 1:10
stopifnot(
  class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer"),
  sum(a) >= 100
)

> Error: sum(a) >= 100 is not TRUE
```

which is fine. But, the error message for the the below scenario is not what I expect

```
a <- letters
stopifnot(
  class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer"),
  sum(a) >= 100
)
> Error in sum(a) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I expect it to say

> Error: class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer") is not TRUE

But, it doesnt.

**Are my expectations correct? Is that how stopifnot() is supposed to work?** And how can I make stopifnot() work like that?

Answer (score 2):

`stopifnot` evaluates each of your supplied expressions, and then checks that all of them are `TRUE`. If this isn't the case, it halts and prints an error message, saying which of the expressions failed.

In your example, what's happening is that the *expressions themselves* are triggering an error. It's the evaluation of the expression `sum(a) >= 100` that results in the error message, not `stopifnot` itself.

Comment: Hi @hong :) `stopifnot` produces an error message telling me the first expression which is not all TRUE. So, I expect it not to worry about the second expression onwards when the first expression itself is not all TRUE. So, I expect it to tell me the error message corresponding to the first expression instead of failing trying to evaluate the second expression. I want to know if my expectations are valid? Am I using `stopifnot` properly?

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer about how stopifnot() is supposed to work. But, here is how to achieve what is expected

Consider using the hadley's assertthat package. It works as expected

```
a <- letters
assertthat::assert_that(
  class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer"),
  sum(a) >= 100
)

> Error: `%in%`(x = class(a), table = c("numeric", "integer")) is not TRUE
```

It also gives more useful error messages. The above error message is not a really good example of that. Consider the below scenario

```
a <- 1:10
assert_that(
  class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer"),
  sum(a) >= 100
)

> Error: sum(a) not greater than or equal to 100
```

Also, here's how stopifnot() can be made to work like that. So, now for the same scenario

```
stopifnot                        <- function (...) {
  ll                             <- lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)
  n                              <- length(ll)
  if (n == 0L) {
    return(invisible())
  }

  mc                             <- match.call()
  for (i in 1L:n) {
    if (!(is.logical(r <- lazyeval::lazy_eval(ll[[i]])) && !anyNA(r) && all(r))) {
      ch <- deparse(mc[[i + 1]], width.cutoff = 60L)
      if (length(ch) > 1L) {
        ch <- paste(ch[1L], "....")
      }
      stop(sprintf(ngettext(length(r), "%s is not TRUE", "%s are not all TRUE"), ch), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
    }
  }

  invisible()
}

a <- letters
stopifnot(
  class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer"),
  sum(a) >= 100
)
> Error: class(a) %in% c("numeric", "integer") is not TRUE
```